# How to redirect 2 pages back with express.js / node.js

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

After a user logged in, I'm trying to redirect him to the same page that he was before the login.

Example: If the user was on the home page before he clicked on the login link, I would like to send him back to the home page if he successfully logged in. (And do the same for every page a user could be on before he came to the login page)

The code should look something like that:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local",
    {
        successRedirect: "two pages back",
        failureRedirect: "/login"
    }), (req, res)=> {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.redirect("/login");
        }
});
```

I've tried this:

```
successRedirect: "back"
```

but it redirects the user back to the login page.

Thanks for your help, I'm using express.js / node.js /passport.js!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure out how to do it.

First, when a GET request is made to the login page, you need to store the user's current page (req.headers.referer) and send it back when you render the login view.

```
router.get("/login", (req, res)=> {
    res.render("login", {referer:req.headers.referer});
});
```

After, inside your login form, you need to put the referer as the value of an hidden input. (I'm using ejs templates here)

```
<input type="hidden" name="referer" value= <%= referer %> >
```

Finally, if there is a login failure (failureRedirect), redirect the user to the "/login" path.

Otherwise, if the page that the user was before getting on the login page (stored in req.body.referer) is not *undefined* and is not the login page itself, redirect the user to this page; stored in req.body.referer.

Else, redirect the user to the the home page or any page you want.

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local", {failureRedirect: "/login"}), (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.referer && (req.body.referer !== undefined && req.body.referer.slice(-6) !== "/login")) {
        res.redirect(req.body.referer);
    } else {
        res.redirect("/");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this could be to store the user's current page when they click the login link.  There are a number of ways you could achieve this, but the simplest would probably be to use the `referer` property of the `req.headers` object.

So in the context of your question, something like this should work:

```
router.post("/login", passport.authenticate("local",
{
    successRedirect: req.headers.referer,      //should redirect to page prior to login
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}), (req, res)=> {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.redirect("/login");
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work because req is not defined.